# Navigation Controller not working in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

```
if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "notification") as? NotificationPage {
    if let navigator = navigationController {
        navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The above code  used in my **Swift 3** project. It was working fine but sudden when I used more then 1 navigation then code is not working.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: How did you get this `navigationController `? Did you checked if it is not `nil`?

Comment: yes i did check it it wasn't nil

Comment: from which class do you inherit `NotificationPage`?

Comment: From the Main class

Comment: Did you set the rootViewController?

Comment: Nope it does not mean 1 navigation, it simply means that once the process did fine but when the program is running from the second time it does not allow this code of navigation to work.

Comment: Yes @kd02 i have set the rootViewController